Why adding two normal distributions gives rise to new normal distributions?
So my reasoning is that since each normal distribution is a symmetric distribution. For every P(X_1=x_1) and when adding to another normal-distribution P(X_2=x_2) gives rise to a new distribution like x_1+x_2 = x_3 where x_3 belongs to the new distribution.
I just need an intuitive explanation.

What happens when you add two quadratics with positive leading coefficients?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Sycorax they just add up to become another quadratic function with the summation of  coefficients

The thing is why adding two normal distributions gives rise to another distribution. These distributions have different probabilities at different x values. If we add them up we get another normal on the right side of the axes. But how is this possible which property we are using?

Write down the density of the normal distribution; key intuitive fact is the quadratic in the expression. Or search the site for any of the large number of threads on this topic.

@Sycorax alright thanks

What is your definition of a Normal distribution?  For many people, the starting point is that its cumulant generating function is purely a quadratic.  Since the cgf of the sum of two independent random variables is the sum of their cgfs, the result is immediate.  If your definition readily implies this fact about cgfs, you're in good shape.  Otherwise, how exactly do you define or characterize Normal distributions?  We need to know that so we can determine how best to proceed.

How has this question come to you? Are you, for instance, in a 3rd or 4th level probabiliy course with calculus?

I could resort to convolution, and its properties; but that would not be very intuitive. I could also resort to entropy, but that is probably even less intuitive. Of course, there are all the mathematical derivations, but intuitive they are not.
The best I could come up with, is to resort to CLT (Central Limit Theorem). Is it intuitive? So maybe I am just moving the goalposts, but maybe it helps.
But first, let's say that it is the sum of 2 independent normal variables which is normal, not just two normals (the real condition is independent or jointly distributed, but...). It is easy to find correlated normals which do not sum to a normal.
So the CLT states that, if you sum a very large number of independent, identically distributed (i.i.d) variables, you will end up asymptotically with a normal distribution. So we can say that a normal distribution is the sum of an infinity of i.i.d random variables (the PDF of which we do not know, nor need to; but for any given normal PDF, there exists one -or in fact more- such original PDF).  And in fact, the CLT can be extended to sums of non-identically distributed random variables (under some conditions).
Then if we take the first normal, it is a sum of an infinity of random variables. To it, we add a 2nd normal, which itself is the sum of another infinity of random variables. Each infinite sum has already reached a point of "asymptotic normalcy", and has  basically nowhere else to go. So all it could possibly be is normal. (and yes, this "intuition" is basically beating around the bush of maximal entropy, w/o saying it. Btw, an "intuition" for the CLT itself can also be derived from the entropy concept). We are just piling infinity on top of infinity, we are just adding more fuel to the CLT's fire, and all we can get to is to another normalcy. All we can do is change the mean and sd, but not the normal "shape". Or, very simplified, $CLT+CLT=CLT$.
And from there on, we can easily generalize to a sum of any number of normals.

I think a convolution is perfectly reasonable way to understand the phenomenon. It also happens to be a precise mathematical tool to formally prove the statement, but it also enables one to visualize the addition and check that the result is not surprising. Of course, convolution builds on a foundation of calculus - in fact, all intuition is formed on at least some foundation of knowledge and experience.

The problem with CLT is that one assumes the variables are IID.  In the case of adding two normals, the surprising fact is that if X has mean 0 and Y has mean 10, the result is normal and not a bimodal value. The latter assumption, a rookie mistake, comes from adding the probability densities when the convolution is the operator performed on the densities.

@AdamO, the CLT even works for non i.d. variables (still independent)., with some conditions on the moments (Lyapunov CLT, or Lindeberg CLT). Yes, the conditions are not met for any sum, of any different distributions, but they are, among others,  for sum of independent non i.d. normals (because of finite means and variances), and they are for pretty much any real world distribution (again, because of finite means and variances)

Even so, all CLTs are asymptotic results. The difference is profound in terms of the language we use expressing probability, hypothesis testing, and uncertainty. Methodologically, the proof for the CLT is quite different than showing the additivity of normal distributions, and one must argue apropos of nothing if the CLT is really an intuitive result per se. I think we are all challenged by OP's question which lacks considerable detail.

I agree that the CLT is asymptotic. And the "intuitive" explanation I suggested is only asymptotic. And Ido not try to prove the CLT via the additivity of normal distributions (just the reverse). Now, I agree that it is not a given that the CLT is intuitive, and I specifically commented on this. And I also agree that such an intuitive explanation of the additivity of normals is quite challenging (in fact frustratingly so). Hence my submission, which indeed may just switch the question to "why is the CLT intuitive?". And hence my following this question, to see what others propose.

@jginestet thanks for the reply just like AdamO said the question lacked considerable detail. I recently talked with a professor and he said that convolutions is one way to describe it. So your approach is right.  He specified where adding each individual x from r.v. X, we would generate another r.v. X whose support function we don't know about and normal being symmetric it works.

@jginestet Thanks for your help :)

Your reasoning is, unfortunately, not correct. Symmetry does not guarantee closure under addition. What I mean by "closure" is that for any two random variables $f_x$, $f_y$ belonging to a parametric family (normal, exponential, Poisson), this parametric family is closed under addition if the variable $Z=X+Y$ has density $f_z$ belonging to the same parametric family. Consider $U_1$ and $U_2$ from uniform $(0, \theta_1)$ and $(0, \theta_2)$ distributions respectively - both symmetric, but the sum of uniforms is triangular. On the other hand, Gamma random variables are not symmetric but, having common scale parameter, the sum of Gammas are distributed Gamma.
To gain the intuition, I find the below GIFs enlightening on explaining the process of convolution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Visual_explanation What you are hoping to see, therefore, is passing one density against another as a "filter" and hoping that the resulting convolution shows a density bearing a common shape typical of that density. The first example shows just such a triangle density arising from the "convolution" of uniform densities. More justification is provided here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions

A good site for illustrated convolutions (and for the CLT, or addition of Gaussians) may also be https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/YM6Qgiz9RT7EmeFpp/how-long-does-it-take-to-become-gaussian

And the previous post on the same site explains the CLT based on convolutional "smoothing"; https://www.lesswrong.com/s/AaKNSG7caKMFmPWtn/p/qs8R7EZqG7QzTsFAZ

@AdamO thanks a lot
